# Installed packages with pip are not shown in pip freeze?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm using `virtualenv` and `pip` on Debian Wheezy. I'm having an odd problem where packages appear to install OK, but then aren't visible in the virtualenv.

This is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
Django==1.7.7
psycopg2==2.5.4
django-geojson==2.6.0
```

If I install it with `pip` from inside my virtualenv, it says everything has been installed:

```
(.venv)$ sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.7.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2==2.5.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-geojson==2.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django-geojson==2.6.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 3))
Cleaning up...
```

But then if I do `pip freeze` to check what is installed, it looks like `pip` thinks I have a completely different set of packages, and in particular it doesn't see `djgeojson` there:

```
(.venv)$ pip freeze
Django==1.7.4
argparse==1.2.1
coverage==3.7.1
distribute==0.6.24
django-debug-toolbar==1.2.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
psycopg2==2.5.4
requirements==0.1
setproctitle==1.1.8
sqlparse==0.1.14
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

And if I fire up a Python terminal, Python can't see `djgeojson`.

Why is this happening? It is quite confusing.

Comment: I think the problem is that pip is installing things to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, but then that isn't on `sys.path`. But why on earth would pip choose to install packages to somewhere that isn't on its own path?

Comment: Why are you using sudo to install and then pip freezing without sudo?

Comment: OK, if I run `sudo pip freeze` I see the same versions of packages. So does what `pip` sees depend on which Linux user you are running it as? That's... surprising.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you've installed requirements with sudo and they were installed in your system python library folder instead and not in your virtual environment's `venv` library.

What to do? Run the same command but this time without sudo: `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This will run pip from the virtual environment and install packages to the right place.

When you activate a virtual environment e.q with `source path/to/my/venv/bin/acivate` the path variable `$PATH` of your current user is updated and then when you run something with sudo, this new $PATH that you've just updated when activating the virtual environment is no longer the same. Same thing happens when you open a new shell window or logs in as a different user with `su` or running `sudo`, `$PATH` variable is not a global system one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that if I try to install the packages without sudo I get permissions errors: `(.venv)$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.7.7 (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 1))
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django
  Source in ./.venv/build/Django has the version 1.7, which does not match the requirement Django==1.7.7 (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 1))
Source in ./.venv/build/Django has version 1.7 that conflicts with Django==1.7.7 (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 1))
Storing complete log in /home/me/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: Then if I try to run `(.venv)$ pip uninstall Django`, in order to get rid of the conflict, I get `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/webapps/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'`. Can I fix this without using `sudo`?

Comment: I guess I could use `sudo` to delete everything in `/webapps/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg-info` - that might work? But I'm always nervous about deleting files rather than uninstalling using the 'official' route.

Comment: These permissions errors are quite confusing - Django must have installed to `/webapps/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` when I was installing it as not-superuser, but now it won't let me remove it unless I make myself superuser - what's that about?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about `$PATH`, I didn't understand that properly.

Comment: Correct, your last comment answers your question. As you have all your requirements in the requirements.txt you can remove the current one `sudo rm -rf /webapps/.venv/`, then create a new one `virtualenv /webapps/.venv`, activate this one `source /webapps/.venv/bin/activate` and install requirements with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Just make a new virtualenv and install your requirements.txt again.

Comment: @TimRijavec thank you for your explanations. That works, and I think I've finally grasped why `sudo pip install` is a bad idea :)