# "pip freeze -r" lists package as not installed, but "pip install -r" finds the package

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Title pretty much sums it up. Output for reference:

```
❯ pip freeze -r requirements.txt
Django==1.7.10
Pillow==2.9.0
PyYAML==3.11
Requirement file contains argparse==1.2.1, but that package is not installed
betterpath==0.2.2

❯ pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.7.10 in /Users/***/.virtualenvs/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow==2.9.0 in /Users/***/.virtualenvs/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyYAML==3.11 in /Users/***/.virtualenvs/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse==1.2.1 in /Users/***/.virtualenvs/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): betterpath==0.2.2 in /Users/***/.virtualenvs/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
```

Comment: Why screenshots instead of pasting the text?

Comment: No specific reason. Didn't know there was a guideline either way. However, text is indeed better.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388447/installed-packages-with-pip-are-not-shown-in-pip-freeze and made sure there's not path error in the installation? (due to sudo pip...)

Comment: I believe the paths are okay. The "pip install -r" commands lists the paths where the packages are installed. They all are installed to the right virtualenv path.