# Can't install new packages or list existing packages in virtual environment with pip

Tags: python, django, pip

## **Update / Solution:**

**Found a fix/workaround in the answer to this question:
[Pip installing packages to global site-packages when inside virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822363/pip-installing-packages-to-global-site-packages-when-inside-virtual-environment).
Like the OP of that question, I'm also running Manjaro Linux with the latest updates.**

When trying to install the django import_export module with `pip install django-import-export` into my virtual environment, it indicates that it was successfully installed, however, when I try to use the import_export module in my project, I receive an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_export'`.  I'm also unable to list any previously installed apps with `pip list` or `pip freeze`, and trying to upgrade the pip version using `pip install --upgrade pip` also says the new version is successfully installed, but isn't installed within my virtual environment.

I've made sure to activate my virtual environment with `source /home/travis/Documents/Python/Django/Projects/issuetracker/.env/bin/activate`.

Output from `pip install django-import-export`:

```
(.env) [travis@spooky issuetracker]$ pip install django-import-export
Collecting django-import-export
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/7a/ddd9aef718243504e7715bda9bb5a100cfc353be37dc819d9914a7073cba/django_import_export-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tablib (from django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/c7/cb74031b330cd94f3580926dc707d148b4ba9138449fc9f433cb79e640d8/tablib-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting diff-match-patch (from django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/2a/5ba07def0e9107d935aba62cf632afbd0f7c723a98af47ccbcab753d2452/diff-match-patch-20181111.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: django>=1.8 in ./.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-import-export) (2.2.4)
Collecting openpyxl>=2.4.0 (from tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/39/942a406621c1ff0de38d7e4782991b1bac046415bf54a66655c959ee66e8/openpyxl-2.6.3.tar.gz
Collecting xlwt (from tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/48/def306413b25c3d01753603b1a222a011b8621aed27cd7f89cbc27e6b0f4/xlwt-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting xlrd (from tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/16/63576a1a001752e34bf8ea62e367997530dc553b689356b9879339cf45a4/xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports.csv (from tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/26/a6bd68f13e0f38fbb643d6e497fc3462be83a0b6c4d43425c78bb51a7291/backports.csv-1.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting odfpy (from tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/7d/8f6d1f2a4683be362b101c00232b4c3839e4e4a90e0945d8d43ec6aa671d/odfpy-1.4.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyyaml (from tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/e8/b3212641ee2718d556df0f23f78de8303f068fe29cdaa7a91018849582fe/PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in ./.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django>=1.8->django-import-export) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django>=1.8->django-import-export) (2019.2)
Collecting jdcal (from openpyxl>=2.4.0->tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/da/572cbc0bc582390480bbd7c4e93d14dc46079778ed915b505dc494b37c57/jdcal-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting et_xmlfile (from openpyxl>=2.4.0->tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/28/a99c42aea746e18382ad9fb36f64c1c1f04216f41797f2f0fa567da11388/et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting defusedxml (from odfpy->tablib->django-import-export)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/74/9b387472866358ebc08732de3da6dc48e44b0aacd2ddaa5cb85ab7e986a2/defusedxml-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: jdcal, et-xmlfile, openpyxl, xlwt, xlrd, backports.csv, defusedxml, odfpy, pyyaml, tablib, diff-match-patch, django-import-export
  Running setup.py install for et-xmlfile ... done
  Running setup.py install for openpyxl ... done
  Running setup.py install for odfpy ... done
  Running setup.py install for pyyaml ... done
  Running setup.py install for diff-match-patch ... done
Successfully installed backports.csv-1.0.7 defusedxml-0.6.0 diff-match-patch-20181111 django-import-export-1.2.0 et-xmlfile-1.0.1 jdcal-1.4.1 odfpy-1.4.0 openpyxl-2.6.3 pyyaml-5.1.2 tablib-0.13.0 xlrd-1.2.0 xlwt-1.3.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.2, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Python version:

```
(.env) [travis@spooky issuetracker]$ python -V
Python 3.7.4
```

Pip version:

```
(.env) [travis@spooky issuetracker]$ pip -V
pip 19.2.2 from /home/travis/Documents/Python/Django/Projects/issuetracker/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

.env/bin/pip:

```
#!/home/travis/Documents/Python/Django/Projects/issuetracker/.env/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

I'm not sure when this stopped working, since I was previously able to successfully install other packages into the same virtual environment. How can I ensure that pip is installing packages correctly into my virtual environment?

## **Update:**

It seems that pip is installing into the .local/lib/python3.7/site-packages directory instead of .env/lib/python3.7/site-packages.

Comment: Try to activate your virtualenv and type command "pip freeze", you can see all packages inside virtualenv. And additional you can verify site-packages path. Path is env/lib/python<<version>>/site-packages

Comment: `pip freeze` doesn't show any output.

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960199/pip-freeze-does-not-show-all-installed-packages/45207675 and verify

Comment: For issue like permission error, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388447/installed-packages-with-pip-are-not-shown-in-pip-freeze/29388603. I hope it helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix/workaround in the answer to this question:

[Pip installing packages to global site-packages when inside virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822363/pip-installing-packages-to-global-site-packages-when-inside-virtual-environment)

Like the OP of that question, I'm also running Manjaro Linux with the latest updates.