# Pip installing packages to global site-packages when inside virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

Let me preface this by stating that I have read [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv/20954767) and it did not solve my problem.

When creating a virtual environment using `python -m venv venv` (or any other name) and then activating said venv using `source venv/bin/activate`, running `pip install [package]` actually installs the package to the (user) global python site packages, located in `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`.

Interestingly, it always tries to install the packages and does not recognize that they are installed globally, meaning it is looking for packages initially in the correct location.

I am running Manjaro Linux, and running the latest updates.

I created this virtual environment in `~/Stuff/tests/venv`.
Running `which pip` and `which python` returns:

```py
(venv) angelin@asgard:~/Stuff/tests/venv $ which pip
/home/angelin/Stuff/tests/venv/bin/pip
(venv) angelin@asgard:~/Stuff/tests/venv $ which python
/home/angelin/Stuff/tests/venv/bin/python
```

Checking said pip executable shows the correct shebang:

```
(venv) angelin@asgard:~/Stuff/tests/venv $ cat bin/pip
#!/home/angelin/Stuff/tests/venv/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
```

My path, when inside the virtualenv, points to the virtual environment first, too:

```
(venv) angelin@asgard:~/Stuff/tests/venv $ echo $PATH
/home/angelin/Stuff/tests/venv/bin:/home/angelin/.local/bin:...
```

Manually running `python -m pip` or `venv/bin/python venv/bin/pip` produces the same results.
The `PYTHONPATH` variable is not set.
I have tried reinstalling python and pip using `pacman -S python python-pip`, but I believe that only reinstalls the global package (located in `/usr/bin` and I didn't want to mess with the `.local` install in case I broke something even more than it is.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Use the `--prefix` option?

Comment: With which executable? Neither python, pip or the venv module have such option as far as I know (and the --help option shows)

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-prefix

Comment: @Goyo Using the prefix option gives me an error stating that I can't use it with `--user`, even though I am not passing said argument: 

```
(venv) angelin@asgard:~/Stuff/tests $ pip install --prefix=/home/angelin/Stuff/tests/venv/lib/python3.7/ requests
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--prefix' as they imply different installation locations
```

Any idea where it could be setting the `--user` option?

Comment: Try [`pip config [--user|--global|--site] list`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/)

Comment: @phd Using it without any optionals returns nothing, using anything else returns an error similar to: `Need exactly one file to operate upon (--user, --venv, --global) to perform.`. Interestingly, it complains that the `--site` option does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a temporary workaround in place.

`/etc/pip.conf` contained:

```
[global]
user = true
```

There was no local pip config file, this was causing it to always pass the `--user` option. I am not sure how to configure my local file correctly, but I created it and set `user = false` and will just manually pass the `--user` option outside of venvs.

This doesn't feel like a proper fix, as it was working normally 2 days ago and the global file hasn't been changed in more than a month. Maybe an update broke something, who knows. If anyone else has a better solution, feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on 20.04.6 LTS. My case was I upgraded standard 3.8 to 3.10, then using 3.10 to create venv giving me this problem.

Simply add pip.conf under your `~/.venv` , and put

```
[install]
site=true
```

Now pip install saves to `~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/` instead of `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`

==

This might be helpful.

Activate your .venv and run `$pip config -v list`

Should see something like:

```
For variant 'site', USER try loading '/home/USER/.venv/pip.conf'
```

Make sure you put the conf in right place. =)